# Spring injection: @Component over native singleton

Tags: java, spring, singleton

Instead of creating the usual Java singletons/static classes, is it best practice to use the @Component annotation instead to let Spring handle the initialization? Or is it abusive?

Answer (score 2):

It is a good practice and abusive. It encourages loose coupling - your objects are not aware of any factories. It also allows you to initialize your beans by using an applicationContext.xml. Spring has gained a lot of popularity in recent years due to its Inversion of Control idiom.

Comment: Good practice yet abusive... I'm confused here. What would you do in your opinion and why?

Comment: I would use Spring @Component annotations. Why do you think it's abusive? It's a de-facto standard nowadays.